# #limit_validation_errors not working for reset button?

Tags: forms, 9

I have a page view with some exposed filters (i.e. main content page). Some exposed filters are auto-complete fields (i.e. user references). So if I type some rubbish for user name and submit form I get error that user doesn't exist, which is correct.
However if I press button "Reset" instead of emptying all the fields and really resetting the form it gets validated and I get error same as with submitting it? Why is that?

Anyway, I tried to solve this by adding in my hook_form_alter row like:

```
//  unset ($form['actions']['reset']);
$form['actions']['reset']['#limit_validation_errors'] = [];
```

So there really is `$form['action']['reset']` (i.e. if I unset it Reset button disappears), but that form altering does nothing - validation still happens when I press reset button and instead emptying auto-complete field(s) I get validation error.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You have referred to a `submit` button and a `reset` button in your post, but only showed a bit of code relating to one of them.

Comment: My mistake, in code it's really 'reset', but I typed it wrong in text after. And that's the only code I added related to this issue.

Comment: If I change reset button type from "submit" to "button" it seems to work, at least for some view pages.

Comment: Type `button` does not trigger validation or submission handlers, so that makes sense.